# I there a way to get image ressource from a Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-imageview, android-resources

I want to get an image from app ressource via Sevice to set a certain attribute.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You would do it the same way that you would using any other `Context`. For example, you could call `getResources()` on the `Service`, then [call `getDrawable()` on the `Resources` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) to get a `Drawable` for your given drawable resource ID.